# Strange spaceManager warnings when trying to build my app? cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.5, chipmunk

I am making a game using cocos2d and spaceManager and every time I try to build I keep getting 9 warnings just like this one:

```
ld: warning: instance method 'initWithBodyName:spaceManager:' in category from /Users/Stephen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tire_Hoops-ehsypaujneeleibuwmnnfbiukpry/Build/Intermediates/Tire Hoops.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tire Hoops.build/Objects-normal/i386/cpCCSprite+PhysicsEditor-86CB95D6892249C.o conflicts with same method from another category
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I had duplicated classes in my project.